# node workspaces — require local package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-workspaces

I am using the `workspaces` feature of [node/npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) and the layout is like that:

```
.
+-- package.json
`-- packages
   `-- p1
      `-- package.json
   `-- p2
      `-- package.json
```

```
./package.json

{
  …
  "workspaces": [
    "./packages/*"
  ],
  …
  "dependcies": { … }
  …
}
```

`npm install` and everything is working to far. But now I would like to add the package `p1` as dependency to package `p2`. But how do I have to do that? Naively I have tried that:

```
./packages/p2/package.json

{
  …
  "dependencies": {
    "p1": "*"
  }
  …
}
```

But that yields an error on install, telling me that `p1` cannot be found the registry.

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE - using npm cli**
From the project root directory run

```
npm i ./packages/p1 -w packages/p2
```

The `./` is a **MUST** or else npm will confuse the install as a package install from npm registry vs from a local directory.

**Manual Workaround**
Manually add **p1** as a local dependency by providing **p1's** relative path in **p2** package.json, so in your example:

```
./packages/p2/package.json

{
  …
  "dependencies": {
    "p1": "file:../p1"
  }
  …
}
```

Then you'll need to run `npm install` in the **p2** package.

I found that solution from a LinkedIn article [Things I wish I had known when I started JavaScript monorepo with Lerna](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/things-i-wish-had-known-when-started-javascript-monorepo-gorej/?).

Comment: Not quite what he wanted. His question is relating to npm workspaces. 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces?v=true

Answer (score 3):

```
.
+-- package.json
`-- packages
   `-- p1
      `-- package.json
   `-- p2
      `-- package.json
```

With NPM workspaces, do not specify your dependency to `p1` in `./packages/p2/package.json`.

NPM will figure out your local dependencies automatically.

if your specify `p1` in your dependencies, it will install an outdated version under your projects P2 `node_modules`. To fix this when that happens:

1. Delete that old version of P1 under the `node_modules` of P2
2. Remove the `P1` dependency in `./packages/p2/package.json`.
3. Rebuild everything.

Wish they explained this better in the docs: docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces?v=true

Answer (score 2):

That naive approach should work, which makes me suspect that maybe there's something wrong in your setup. Couple of things you can double-check:

- is the `"name"` field in `./p1/package.json` exactly `p1` ? (for example, if you're using scoped names then it might be that you need to use `@scopename/p1` in `./p2/package.json` `"dependencies"` instead)
- do you have the latest version of the **npm cli**? `npm -v` (currently v7.23.0)
- make sure the `p1` package is properly symlinked in the `./node_modules` folder, e.g: `ls -l ./node_modules/p1`

> But how do I have to do that?

Given that everything is properly setup, you can add packages as dependencies of a workspace (including another workspace) using the `-w <workspace-name>` argument, e.g: (adding `p1` as a dep of `p2`) `npm install p1 -w p2`, ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces#adding-dependencies-to-a-workspace